# Regex to pull log message that may or may not appear after a pipe character

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk

I'm trying to extract data into a `Splunk Data Model` Regex Attribute.  The data I'm trying to extract from the events get logged in a couple of ways.

```
2014-07-17 21:29:43,620 UTC [http-apr-8080-exec-143] ERROR c.s.b.b.s.impl.HttpRequestLogFilter - Apps="UNKNOWN" ReqIP="1.1.1.1" ReqProt="https" | FAILED: 500 POST /something/v1/something/v1/group elapsed:14


2014-07-17 21:29:42,797 UTC [persistentScheduler_Worker-6] INFO c.s.b.s.b.svc.impl.DocumentIndexJob - data source UNKNOWN\_163\_2 (Customer Information), customer 1, institution 1 is still indexing
```

I would love it if the regular expression would return the following values from the two lines:

```
c.s.b.b.s.impl.HttpRequestLogFilter - FAILED: 500 POST /something/v1/something/v1/group elapsed:14

c.s.b.s.b.svc.impl.DocumentIndexJob - data source UNKNOWN\_163\_2 (Customer Information), customer 1, institution 1 is still indexing
```

I have come up with regex expressions that handle each situation separately, but not one that will **handle both situations and put them into the same field**.

*Pulling everything after the pipe character*:

```
\S* \S* \S* \[.*\]\s+[A-Z]+\s+.*\|(?<message>.\*)
```

*Pulling everything without a pipe character*:

```
\S* \S* \S* \[.*\]\s+[A-Z]+\s+(.*\||(?<message>.\*))
```

The latest idea that I was working on was to do a *negative lookahead and extract the data that doesn't come before a pipe character*.

```
\S* \S* \S* \[.*\]\s+[A-Z]+\s+(?<message>.*(?!\|))
```

Every combination that I try either matches everything, nothing, or half of what I want.  So hopefully some regex master can assist me.  I've tried finding an answer that works online, but I haven't so far.

Comment: can you do a split to array by pipe? then check if element2.length>0 then you have text else no text. One line of code

Comment: No, I can only put in one regex expression.  I cannot do any manipulation beyond a single regex.  For those not familiar with Splunk, the (?<message>) portion is where I specify what data will go into the message field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an OR `|` between two separate Regex cases?

```
ERROR (\S+ - ).+\| (.+)|INFO (\S+ - )(.+)
```

works for me.  They even both have two capture groups for the message and the details.

Pretty much you start matching at either `ERROR` or `INFO`, grab up to the hyphen `-`, and then look for the rest of the string. The errors will have a pipe, so ignore everything up until then, and the info output won't have a pipe, so just grab everything after the hyphen as well.

Here is a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aI8eB7/2) on Regex101

EDIT:

I believe I have the proper solution [here](http://regex101.com/r/aI8eB7/6).

```
.+ (\S+ - )(?:.+\| )?
```

This captures the last non-space characters before the `-` and then goes on to encapsulate up to a bar *if it exists* and replaces the entire front of the string with the capture group.

Comment: To clarify, any log level (ERROR, INFO, WARN, etc.) may or may not have pipe characters.  While it works on Regex101... it's not working in Splunk.  When there is a pipe character, it still grabs the entire message (everything before the pipe and after).

\S* \S* \S* \[.*\]\s+[A-Z]+\s+(?<message>((\S+ - ).+\| (.+)|(\S+ - )(.+)))

Comment: @RobertPenberthy I think I have a solution for you using regex substitution. Instead of trying to capture just the data you want, capture the data you don't want and get rid of it. I've added this solution to the original answer.

Comment: Putting what you provided into the Splunk form I need, I lose the text between the log level and the hyphen... but I got the meat of what I wanted to extract so I'll live without.  Thank you so much!  Here is what it looks like in Splunk form:  `\S* \S* \S* \[.*\]\s+[A-Z]+\s+(\S+ - )(?:.+\| )?(?<message>.*)`